# 'Lazy' geocoding

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, gmaps4rails

Is there any feature in gmaps4rails to process 'lazy' geocoding?

My situation:

I have a database of companies, which has one address. When a company is added manually (only 1 record), there aren't any problems, `process_geocoding` is set to `true` by default.

Once every two weeks, we update our db with an import script. When we use import, we set  `process_geocoding` to `false`, because geocoding slows our import script by 4 - 5 times (in my case - it is unacceptable).

I need lazy a gecoding feature, which can process geocoding `if !address.blank? && lat.blank? && lng.blank?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 1.5 you can do:

```
process_geocoding: lambda { |obj| !obj.address.blank? && obj.lat.blank? && obj.lng.blank? }
```

or:

```
process_geocoding: :method_name
```